# How to execute command in a pod (kubernetes) using API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to execute command in a contianer (in a Kubernetes POD on GKE with kubernetes 1.1.2).

Reading documentation I understood that I can use GET or POST query to open websocket connection on API endpoint to execute command. When I use GET, it does not work completly, returns error. When I try to use POST, something like that could work probably (but it's not):

```
curl 'https://admin:xxx@IP/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/hello-whue1/exec?stdout=1&stderr=1&command=ls' -H "Connection: upgrade" -k -X POST -H 'Upgrade: websocket'
```

repsponse for that is

```
unable to upgrade: missing upgrade headers in request: http.Header{"User-Agent":[]string{"curl/7.44.0"}, "Content-Length":[]string{"0"}, "Accept":[]string{"*/*"}, "Authorization":[]string{"Basic xxx=="}, "Connection":[]string{"upgrade"}, "Upgrade":[]string{"websocket"}}
```

Looks like that should be enough to upgrade post request and start using websocket streams, right? What I'm missing?

I was also pointed that opening websocket with POST is probably violation of websocket protocol (only GET should work?).

Also

Comment: @George: wrong link?

Comment: @George I don't see anything about executing commands in that blog post, especially using API. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try modifying the aiohttp? maybe it can help in your case.

Comment: @George, I tried to do that, no results. I found out that I need upgrade connection to spdy,not to websockets (at least in the version GCP is using)

Comment: As a solution for now I'm just spawning process and execute "kubectl exec" as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have the best time using the [Kubernetes client library](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.1/pkg/client/unversioned), which is the same code the Kubectl uses, but if for some reason that isn't an option, than my best suggestion is to look through [the client library's code for executing remote commands](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/pkg/client/unversioned/remotecommand/remotecommand.go) and seeing what headers it sets.

Comment: I couldn't use kubernetes client library (python). I went through the code, but what I found in the code (before I asked that question) is that only SPDY protocol is supported, but I found in the docs somewhere that websockets should work as well (and probably without websockets as well, not sure now). So I misunderstood something or websocket implementation is missing. Anyway as a workaround I do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373472/how-to-execute-command-in-a-pod-kubernetes-using-api#comment58212217_34373472

Answer (score 2):

Use websocket client it's work.

In my local kuberenetes cluster, the connection metadata like this:

```
ApiServer = "172.21.1.11:8080"
Namespace = "default"
PodName = "my-nginx-3855515330-l1uqk"
ContainerName = "my-nginx"
Commands = "/bin/bash"
```

the connect url:

```
"ws://172.21.1.11:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/my-nginx-3855515330-l1uqk/exec?container=my-nginx&stdin=1&stdout=1&stderr=1&tty=1&command=%2Fbin%2Fbash"
```

On maxos, a wsclient CLI tool: [wscat](https://blog.grandcentrix.net/a-command-line-websocket-client/), you can use it as a test tool:

[image]

You can access the websocket example: "https://github.com/lth2015/container-terminal"

Comment: maybe it's fixed now!? What version of kubernetes do you use? I think I tired that long time ago last time)

Comment: my kubernetes version is 1.2.0

Comment: ah, that's it, I probably used https instead of ws://, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can using a websocket client to exec into a pod, [a quick demo](https://github.com/lth2015/container-terminal).

javascript code shows how to connect to kubernetes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('exampleApp', ['kubernetesUI'])
        .config(function(kubernetesContainerSocketProvider) {
            kubernetesContainerSocketProvider.WebSocketFactory = "CustomWebSockets";
        })
        .run(function($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.baseUrl = "ws://localhost:8080";
            $rootScope.selfLink = "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/my-nginx-3855515330-l1uqk";
            $rootScope.containerName = "my-nginx";
            $rootScope.accessToken = "";
            $rootScope.preventSocket = true;
        })
        /* Our custom WebSocket factory adapts the url */
        .factory("CustomWebSockets", function($rootScope) {
            return function CustomWebSocket(url, protocols) {
                url = $rootScope.baseUrl + url;
                if ($rootScope.accessToken)
                    url += "&access_token=" + $rootScope.accessToken;
                return new WebSocket(url, protocols);
            };
        });
</script>
```

you can test it in other language.