# Kubernetes pod exec API exception: Response must not include 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header if not present in request

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to setup a websocket connection to the Kubernetes Pod Exec API, based on the suggestions given in this SO post: [How to execute command in a pod (kubernetes) using API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373472/how-to-execute-command-in-a-pod-kubernetes-using-api).
Here's what I have done so far -

1. Installed Simple Web Socket Client extension in Chrome.
2. Started `kubectl proxy --disable-filter=true` to run proxy with WS connections allowed. `kubectl.exe` version is 1.8.
3. Used address `ws://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/nginx-3580832997-26zcn/exec?container=nginx&stdin=1&stdout=1&stderr=1&tty=1&command=%2Fbin%2Fsh` in the Chrome extension to connect to the `exec` api.

When I click connect, Chrome reports back an error with the message -

`Error during WebSocket handshake: Response must not include 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header if not present in request`

Apparently, kubectl is sending back empty `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header in the response and Chrome is taking offense to that.

I tried changing the code of Simple Web Socket Client `open` method to send empty protocols parameter to the Websocket client creation call, like - `ws = new WebSocket(url, []);` to coax Chrome in sending empty header in request, but Chrome doesn't send empty header.

So what can be done to directly connect to the `exec` in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the code in https://github.com/kubernetes-ui/container-terminal/blob/master/container-terminal.js, found that `exec` [uses](https://github.com/kubernetes-ui/container-terminal/blob/master/container-terminal.js#L197) `base64.channel.k8s.io` protocol. The Simple Web Socket Client code wouldn't have worked because of this and also that the stream communication is in base64, not plain text.

Leaving this as an answer for other folks trying to implement a WS based terminal emulator... as @janos-lenart mentioned, the code is pretty new and there may be issues using it in different browsers, best bet at this point is to read example code and start from there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue; [`kubectl proxy` does not support websockets](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25126). (You can verify this easily by starting up `kubectl proxy` and then attempting `kubectl --server=http://127.0.0.1:8001 exec ...`; you will receive the message `error: unable to upgrade connection: <h3>Unauthorized</h3>` if the filter is enabled and `Error from server (BadRequest): Upgrade request required` if the filter is disabled).

The [confusion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#so-many-proxies) might come from the fact that the `kube-apiserver` proxy does support websockets, but that proxy is different from the `kubectl proxy`.

As I see you have 3 options now (in order of difficulty):

- Access `kube-apiserver` directly. You will likely need authentication that `kubectl proxy` is handling for you now
- Use SockJS, this is what Kubernetes Dashboard does for the [exec feature](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/pull/1939)
- Fix [#25126](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25126)

Comment: `kubectl` supports it when you use it with the `--disable-filter=true` flag. See [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/32026). I have got this working in Firefox :) using Simple Web Socket Client. Apparently Chrome throws exception when an empty `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header is returned, while FF is chill about it.

Comment: Ah, that is fairly new code in #49534, probably sharp at the edges :) So I should have written `kubectl proxy` does not *properly* support websockets *yet*. I suggest accessing the `kube-apiserver` directly until.

Comment: Thanks @janos, I investigated the issue further and it seems to be affecting the Chrome extension I was using. I was able to successfully use https://github.com/kubernetes-ui/container-terminal to connect with `kubectl proxy` session in Chrome. I found that `exec` [uses](https://github.com/kubernetes-ui/container-terminal/blob/master/container-terminal.js#L197) `base64.channel.k8s.io` protocol while making the connection. Maybe once the feature is more mature, documentation will catch up to mention this.